# In clause versus OR clause performance wise

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, database-performance, query-performance

I have a query as below:

```
select * 
from table_1 
where column_name in ('value1','value2','value3');
```

considering that the data in such a table may be in millions, will the below restructuring help better??

```
select * 
from table_1 where 
column_name = 'value1' 
or column_name = 'value2' 
or column_name ='value3';
```

or

```
select * 
from table_1 
where column_name = any ('value1','value2','value3');
```

I need to know performance benefits also if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: IN and OR are theoretically identical... if you think they're not what did your testing reveal? Have you tested them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IN vs OR of Oracle, which faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514906/in-vs-or-of-oracle-which-faster)

Comment: seriously..??

i had heard that there was performance difference but i am not able to get the exact better one.

Comment: There _can_ be differences in the explain plan as calculated by the optimizer, which would explain differences in performance. If your testing didn't reveal such then that _specific_ query doesn't have this problem.

Comment: If there is any difference it is most likely to be this: develoeprs are much more likely to chuck a thousand values into an `IN` clause than they are to cutn'paste a thouand `or column_name = ` statements.

Comment: It is set that there will be only 3 values that have to be checked no matter what value1,value2,value3 are hard coded, will any change be needed..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query doesn't matter much in case of 3 value checking only.

Oracle will re-write the query anyways to match the best option available.

in case there were more values and that too dynamic then the in clause or inner join could have been better.

its best to leave the query as it is currently

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3rd way which is faster than 'IN' or multiple 'WHERE' conditions:

```
select *
from table_1 as tb1
inner join table_2 as tb2
where tb1.column_name = tb2.column_name
```

Here table_2 (or query) would have required values that were listed in 'IN' and 'WHERE' conditions in your example.

Comment: As i said there are only 3 values in the where clause value1,value2,value3. these are final, why would i go for creating another table and making joins, wouldnt it be slower..??

Comment: If that's relevant then please add it to the question, not just the comment.