# Oracle insert lots of data to temporary table

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle10g

I need to insert 12000 strings into temporary table, 6 characters each. Currently I am doing it with `SELECT Code FROM Articles where Code = '111111' OR Code = '222222' ...`  command that has 400 000 characters and takes 20 seconds to execute. I wonder how can I speed up this process?

I do not need any validation on my codes. They need to be transferred from application to database as part of the query or as command parameter.

I do not really need to do `Select Code From Articles`, but oracle does not support multiple records in `INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (...)`

Comment: Where is the list of codes you're using in the query (111111 etc.) coming from? Another table, a file, user input, ...?

Comment: Good point, added it to question. I think that command parameter is reasonable way.

Comment: How are they held in the application then, and what language/connection type are you using? You may be able to pass an array of values and have it treated as a collection.

Comment: I take those values from mysql database. There is stored procedure that does `SELECT Code FROM Sometable`. My application takes all these codes and tries to pass them to oracle temporary table.

In backend I am using C# with devart MySql driver.

Comment: [Maybe something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6155801/266304), but with your Oracle type created as strings not numbers. You then don't have to construct the statement based on how many values there are, you just pass a single array bind variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AlexPoole pointed out it is best to use table valued parameter.

```
type t_varchar_tab is table of varchar2(10) index by pls_integer;
procedure insert_table(i_id_tab in t_varchar_tab);
```

body:

```
  procedure insert_table(i_id_tab in t_varchar_tab) is
  begin
  -- if You have temporary table You do not want commits here
  forall i in i_id_tab.first .. i_id_tab.last
      insert into MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
      VALUES (i_id_tab(i));
  end ins_test;
```

C#:

```
        using (OracleCommand dbCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            dbCommand.CommandText = "MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE.insert_table";
            dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var inputArray = new OracleParameter
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
                Value = StringList.ToArray()
            };
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(inputArray);
            await dbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Thanks Alex!

Answer (score 2):

`IN` is generally faster than `OR` as it stops evaluating as soon as the condition is met. See previous q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514906/in-vs-or-of-oracle-which-faster)

So:

```
Select code
from Articles
where Code in ('111111','222222')
```

To allow for the extremely large list, tuples:

```
Select code
from Articles
where ('1', Code) in (('1','111111'),
                      ('1','222222')...)
```

Comment: It would have to have multiple `IN` clauses `OR`d together, of course, if there are 12000 values to look for,