# SQL query optimization with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, optimization

I got a challenge from school to optimise this query (this is theoretical question)

Challenge :

```
SELECT 
    n.node_id,
    MIN(LEAST(n.date,ec.date)) date
FROM 
    n, ec
WHERE 
    (n.node_id = ec.node_id_from OR n.node_id = ec.node_id_to)
    AND n.date - ec.date > 0
GROUP BY 
    n.node_id;
```

I make some effort to optimise this query and need to share with guys

```
SELECT   
    n.node_id, LEAST (n.date, ec.date) date
FROM   
    n 
INNER JOIN 
    ec ON (n.node_id = ec.node_id_from OR n.node_id = ec.node_id_to)
WHERE
    n.date - ec.date > 0
```

What I have done: I removed the min function and group by because least function only return least value from string.

Secondly I added the inner join with this query.

Is my solution fine or you have some more better option?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one wants to evaluate the equality of a single column against to 2 or more values then you can use IN instead of multiple OR's:

```
SELECT n.node_id, MIN(ec.date) as date
FROM n 
JOIN ec
  ON n.node_id IN (ec.node_id_from, ec.node_id_to) AND ec.date < n.date
GROUP BY n.node_id;
```

It's more concise, and there's a higher chance that the index on n.node_id will be used (if it exists).

Also, see this old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514906/in-vs-or-of-oracle-which-faster)

And just using `min(ec.date)` instead of `MIN(LEAST(n.date,ec.date))`.
Because the JOIN already forces the `ec.date` to be lower than `n.date` anyway.

Also note that a where clause like

```
where (x >= y and x <= z)
```

can be changed to

```
where (x between y and z)
```

Answer (score 0):

`or` in an `on` clause is a performance killer.  I imagine that you intend:

```
SELECT n.node_id, MIN(LEAST(n.date, ec.date)) date
FROM n join
     ec
     ON (n.node_id = ec.node_id_from OR n.node_id = ec.node_id_to) AND
        n.date > ec.date
GROUP BY n.node_id;
```

Note the parentheses.

If so, you can replace this with:

```
SELECT n.node_id,
       MIN(LEAST(n.date, COALESCE(ec.date, n.date), COALECE(ec1.date, n.date)) date
FROM n LEFT JOIN
     ec
     ON n.node_id = ec.node_id_from AND n.date > ec.date LEFT JOIN
     ec ec2
     ON n.node_id = ec.node_id_to  
GROUP BY n.node_id;
```

Comment: please justify the second query

Comment: if is work for or logic because you remove the `or` operator

Comment: and please tell me what is best solution for performance point of view soluton#1 or solution#2 ?

Comment: First solution is looking fine I  think

Comment: ok but i am waiting for @GordonLinoff responce what he suggest

Comment: @HafizUsmanaftab . . . The first query is what I suppose you intend.  It is not the query that you write (note the parentheses).  The downvote is rude.